# How to list recently deleted files from a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm not even sure if this is easily possible, but I would like to list the files that were recently deleted from a directory, recursively if possible.

I'm looking for a solution that does not require the creation of a temporary file containing a snapshot of the original directory structure against which to compare, because write access might not always be available. **Edit:** If it's possible to achieve the same result by storing the snapshot in a shell variable instead of a file, that would solve my problem.

Something like:

`find /some/directory -type f -mmin -10 -deletedFilesOnly`

**Edit:** OS: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but the command(s) would most likely be running in a variety of Linux boxes or Docker containers, most or all of which should be using `ext4`, and to which I would most likely not have access to make modifications.

Comment: Virtually impossible. Deleted files are *deleted* in Linux -- no built-in safety net. If you wanted to try something REALLY fancy, you could try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files ...but for what you seem to need, that's probably overkill.

Comment: only thing I can think of is IF the file was edited and a backup was kept from editing the file, search for any file in a directory that is such as `foo.bar~` but has no `foo.bar` in the directory thus **assuming** the file was deleted.

Comment: the answer depends on the file system used, not on the operation system itself. the only relation to `linux` is that what you are asking for is not possible for most popular linux file systems.

Comment: but with most file systems many have seen on linux using the CLI interface it is mostly impossible. So you may you tell us what Linux OS you are using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `debugfs` utility,

> debugfs is a simple to use RAM-based file system specially designed
>   for debugging purposes

First, run `debugfs /dev/hda13` in your terminal (replacing `/dev/hda13` with your own disk/partition).

(NOTE: You can find the name of your disk by running `df /` in the terminal).

Once in debug mode, you can use the command `lsdel` to list inodes corresponding with deleted files.

> When files are removed in linux they are only un-linked but their
>   inodes (addresses in the disk where the file is actually present) are
>   not removed

**To get paths** of these deleted files you can use `debugfs -R "ncheck 320236"` replacing the number with your particular inode.

```
Inode   Pathname
320236  /path/to/file
```

From here you can also inspect the contents of deleted files with `cat`. (NOTE: You can also recover from here if necessary).

Great post about this [**here**](http://www.linuxweblog.com/undelete-files).

Comment: `lsdel` shows you inodes that belonged to files that were deleted; is there anyway to see the *names* of the delete files?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to output all the filenames, but you can retrieve the contents of a file with the `cat` command. Like this, `cat <32611>`, replacing the number with the inode you want to check.

Comment: That just gives you the contents of an unknown set of files. The question asked for the identities of the deleted files, not their contents.

Comment: Edited to explain retrieving filenames of deleted files.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work in my case. i have xfs on LVM

Answer (score 2):

So a few things:

1. You may have zero success if your partition is ext2; it works best with ext4
2. df /
3. Fill mount point with result from #2, in my case:

   sudo debugfs /dev/mapper/q4os--desktop--vg-root
4. lsdel
5. q (to exit out of debugfs)
6. sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck 528754' /dev/sda2 2>/dev/null (replace number with one from step #4)

Comment: Since you are formally posting an answer to an older question. It would be most helpful that you support your purported answer with some code and the output that results from using your code.  Try copy and pasting some of the result or even a screen print that demonstrates you code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments & answers guys. `debugfs` seems like an interesting solution to the initial requirements, but it is a bit overkill for the simple & light solution I was looking for; if I'm understanding correctly, the kernel must be built with `debugfs` support and the target directory must be in a `debugfs` mount. Unfortunately, that won't really work for my use-case; I must be able to provide a solution for existing, "basic" kernels and directories.

As this seems virtually impossible to accomplish, I've been able to negotiate and relax the requirements down to listing the *amount* of files that were recently deleted from a directory, recursively if possible.

This is the solution I ended up implementing:

1. A simple `find` command piped into `wc` to count the original number of files in the target directory (recursively). The result can then easily be stored in a shell or script variable, without requiring write access to the file system.

`DEL_SCAN_ORIG_AMOUNT=$(find /some/directory -type f | wc -l)`

2. We can then run the same command again later to get the updated number of files.

`DEL_SCAN_NEW_AMOUNT=$(find /some/directory -type f | wc -l)`

3. Then we can store the difference between the two in another variable and update the original amount.

`DEL_SCAN_DEL_AMOUNT=$(($DEL_SCAN_ORIG_AMOUNT - $DEL_SCAN_NEW_AMOUNT));`
`DEL_SCAN_ORIG_AMOUNT=$DEL_SCAN_NEW_AMOUNT`

4. We can then print a simple message if the number of files went down.

`if [ $DEL_SCAN_DEL_AMOUNT -gt 0 ]; then echo "$DEL_SCAN_DEL_AMOUNT deleted files"; fi;`

5. Return to step 2.

---

Unfortunately, this solution won't report anything if the same amount of files have been created and deleted during an interval, but that's not a *huge* issue for my use case.

To circumvent this, I'd have to store the actual list of files instead of the amount, but I haven't been able to make that work using shell variables. If anyone could figure that out, I'd help me immensely as it would meet the initial requirements!

I'd also like to know if anyone has comments on either of the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lsof -nP | grep -i deleted
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the original question.  The `lsof` command just lists OPEN files; if the files were deleted, they are not going to be open currently.  (There might be a tiny exception, if a process has a file open, another process deletes the file.)

Answer (score -2):

history >> history.txt

Look for all rm statements.

Comment: There are many ways files can be removed other than via `rm` statements.