# Find the reason of a file deletion

Tags: linux

When I run in the terminal a script which compiles different things by running other scripts, it shows up an error, telling me that the file XXX doesn't exist. But it existed before I ran the script. Thus, I would like to find out what script/program/process deleted the file to fix the bug.

I looked at [this](https://serverfault.com/a/198808) but it didn't help me: I am looking for the program at the origin of the deletion, not the user. Additionally, auditctl and iwatch don't exist on the machine I am using.

Please note that I am not interested in [what files are deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883839/how-to-list-recently-deleted-files-from-a-directory) (I perfectly know which).

Also, I can recreate XXX to run again the script.

**How to simply find out what causes the deletion of XXX?**

Comment: You could make it write-protected (`chmod 440 XXX`), and see if some script complains. Are you using `make`? `make` deletes intermediate products.

Comment: `chmod` doesn't work because XXX is actually a symbolic link, so the permissions remain `lrwxrwxrwx` and the file is still deleted. I don't think that XXX is the target of a Makefile. I am also using shell scripts.

Comment: I have replaced XXX by a regular file to use `chmod 440` on it, but it is still deleted. Yet, I am not using `sudo` when I run the first script.

Comment: You must set the owner and group to `root` to prevent non-sudo access for a user.

Comment: Use `chattr +i` instead of `chmod 440`.

Comment: Be aware: ["Not all flags are supported or utilized by all filesystems; refer to filesystem-specific man pages such as btrfs(5), ext4(5), and xfs(5)
for more filesystem-specific details."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind how to debug a shell script:

1. Use `strace`; the function call you're looking for is most probably [`unlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html). From the surrounding calls you should be able to deduct the context the deletion is called from.
2. Switch on command echo with `set -x` or the shebang `#!/bin/bash -x` (for Bash) and grep for `rm` and perhaps [`unlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unlink.1.html). However the deletion may occur in some binary that's called somewhere, in that case you won't find anything this way.

Redirect the output to a file to make searching easier.